# router cannot use method 'get' of undefined, Node

Tags: node.js, module, routes

I am trying to break all the routes out of my main Node server. I made a file /routes/routes.js where I tried to store the routes and export it as a module back to the server. It looks like this:

```
var router = require('express').Router()

    router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        res.sendfile('views/index.html');
    });

    router.get('/about', function (req, res, next) {
        res.sendfile('views/about.html');
    });

    router.get('/websites', function (req, res, next) {
        res.sendfile('views/websites.html');
    });

    router.get('/contact', function (req, res, next) {
        res.sendfile('views/contact.html');
    });

    router.get('/continuinged', function (req, res, next) {
        res.sendfile('views/continuinged.html');
    });

module.exports = router
```

and I have added this line to the server

```
app.use(require('./routes/routes'))
```

However I am getting the error

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
           ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
```

When I try to run the server. I checked the Express docs and they say router should have the HTTP verb methods, so I don't know what to do. Also, please let me know if there is a better way to break the routes out.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error. Reinstalling express fixed everything.

```
$ npm uninstall express
$ npm install express
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try:

```
var router = require('./routes/routes');
app.use('/', router);
```

Comment: didn't work, but how would that be different than requiring ./routes/routes inside app.use()?